# Center within a Bootstrap Well

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been struggling to get the contents of a boostrap well to center. My badge goes to the right, instead of under the arrows, and my arrows (aka, vote buttons) are not centered in the well either. I have attached a screenshot, and here is the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 well">
<div class="votingButton" data-ng-controller="pfcArticleVoting" data-ng-click="upVote(article);">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
</div>
<div class="badge badge-inverse">
    <div>{{article.articlevotes}}</div>
</div>
<div class="votingButton" data-ng-controller="pfcArticleVoting" data-ng-click="downVote(article);">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
</div>
```

Here is the only custom CSS beyond default bootstrap:

```
/* Voting styling */
.votingButton{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Non centered bootstrap well]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `class="text-center"`, that should do the trick, if not you can reposition it using `style="postion: absolute; margin-left: -5px;"`, if you're not too picky about the well size, that might be another problem as "well". fix the size to be a little bigger, that would help.

Comment: Adjusting the well size to col-md-5 and text-center did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Your column width is too small to render correctly.  You need to change `col-md-1 col-sm-1` to `col-md-2 col-sm-2` or reduce the padding inside the div.